# Python, transpose nested values adding None for Missing

Tags: python, defaultdict

One of those days, Can't get me head around this tiny solution.
I am looking for generic solution as the length of the key value pairs in parent and child leg could vary.

so data source looks like following

```
data = {   
    "New York": [
    { "Name": "John", "QTY": 56 },
    { "Name": "Richard", "QTY": 76 }   ],   
    "Texas": [
    { "Name": "John", "QTY": 34 },
    { "Name": "Stephanie", "QTY": 23 }   ],   
    "Florida": [
    { "Name": "Rebecca", "QTY": 28 },
    { "Name": "Richard", "QTY": 43 }   ],   
    "Arizona": [
    {"Name": "Charles", "QTY": 23},
    {"Name": "Anne", "QTY": 31},
    {"Name": "William", "QTY": 44}   ],   
    "New Mexico": [
    {"Name": "Rebecca", "QTY": 56},
    {"Name": "Charles", "QTY": 76},
    {"Name": "Stephen", "QTY": 21},
    {"Name": "William", "QTY": 63}   ],   
    "New Jersey": [
    {"Name": "John", "QTY": 56},
    {"Name": "Richard", "QTY": 76},
    {"Name": "Stephen", "QTY": 45}   ] }
```

Now I want to re-arrange the the dictionary by Name and add values for each state and add None for missing. here is my code

```
output = {}

for x, y in data.items():
    for i in y:
        key = i['Name']
        try:
            output[key].update({x: i['QTY']})
        except:
            output[key] = {x: i['QTY']}

print(output)
```

This gives me result as following

```
{
  "John": {
    "New York": 56,
    "Texas": 34,
    "New Jersey": 56
  },
  "Richard": {
    "New York": 76,
    "Florida": 43,
    "New Jersey": 76
  },
  "Stephanie": {
    "Texas": 23
  },
  "Rebecca": {
    "Florida": 28,
    "New Mexico": 56
  },
  "Charles": {
    "Arizona": 23,
    "New Mexico": 76
  },
  "Anne": {
    "Arizona": 31
  },
  "William": {
    "Arizona": 44,
    "New Mexico": 63
  },
  "Stephen": {
    "New Mexico": 21,
    "New Jersey": 45
  }
}
```

What I will like to have is something like following, order is indeed important

```
{
  "John": {
    "New York": 56,
    "Texas": 34,
    "Florida": None,
    "Arizona": None,
    "New Mexico": None,
    "New Jersey": 56
  },
  .......
  .......
  "Stephen": {
    "New York": None,
    "Texas": None,
    "Florida": None,
    "Arizona": None,
    "New Mexico": 21,
    "New Jersey": 45
  }
}
```

I was wondering if defautldict from collections can be used. But I am not that savvy with it. Folks, remember I need generic solution as the number of states and number os Names can vary.. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: One place to start might be to gather all of the required keys to begin with, then use `dict.get(i)` rather than `dict[i]`, as `get` can return a `None` if the key is not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way to do what your question asks:

```py
nameList = []
nameSet = set()
for state, nameQtyList in data.items():
    for nameQty in nameQtyList:
        name = nameQty["Name"]
        if name not in nameSet:
            nameSet.add(name)
            nameList.append(name)
out = {name:{state:None for state in data} for name in nameList}
for state, nameQtyList in data.items():
    for nameQty in nameQtyList:
        out[nameQty["Name"]][state] = nameQty["QTY"]
```

Explanation:

- walk through the input, compiling names in the sequence of first occurrence in `names`
- initialize the result `out` to have the desired structure, with an initial value of `None` for each `QTY`
- walk through the input again, updating `out` with each `QTY` encountered in the input.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, instead of:

```
try:
    output[key].update({x: i['QTY']})
except:
    output[key] = {x: i['QTY']}
```

do

```
try:
    output[key].update({x: i['QTY']})
except KeyError:
    output[key] = defaultdict(none_generator, {x: i['QTY']})
```

Here, `none_generator` is a function that takes no arguments and returns `None:

```
def none_generator(): pass
```

> Note: You shouldn't be using a bare `except:` clause anyway. You know your `output[key].update(...)` line will produce a `KeyError` if all is working as expected, so only catch a `KeyError` (See [What is wrong with using a bare 'except'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except) for more details)

Now, each value of your `output` dictionary is itself a `defaultdict`, and getting a non-existent key of these `defaultdict`s will return `None:

```
output = {'John': defaultdict(<function none_generator at 0x12256d6c20>, {'New York': 56, 'Texas': 34, 'New Jersey': 56}), 'Richard': defaultdict(<function none_generator at 0x12256d6c20>, {'New York': 76, 'Florida': 43, 'New Jersey': 76}), 'Stephanie': defaultdict(<function none_generator at 0x12256d6c20>, {'Texas': 23}), 'Rebecca': defaultdict(<function none_generator at 0x12256d6c20>, {'Florida': 28, 'New Mexico': 56}), 'Charles': defaultdict(<function none_generator at 0x12256d6c20>, {'Arizona': 23, 'New Mexico': 76}), 'Anne': defaultdict(<function none_generator at 0x12256d6c20>, {'Arizona': 31}), 'William': defaultdict(<function none_generator at 0x12256d6c20>, {'Arizona': 44, 'New Mexico': 63}), 'Stephen': defaultdict(<function none_generator at 0x12256d6c20>, {'New Mexico': 21, 'New Jersey': 45})}
```

`print(output["John"]["Florida"])` prints `None`

---

If you want there to be `None` values explicitly at the keys in the dictionary that do not exist, you're going to have to populate the `output` dictionary first. Then, remake all dictionaries with their missing values set to `None`:

```
output = {}
for x, y in data.items():
    for i in y:
        key = i['Name']
        all_states.add(x)
        try:
            output[key].update({x: i['QTY']})
        except KeyError:
            output[key] = {x: i['QTY']}


for person, person_vals in output.items():
    output[person] = {state: person_vals.get(state, None) for state in data}
```

```
{'John': {'New York': 56,
  'Texas': 34,
  'Florida': None,
  'Arizona': None,
  'New Mexico': None,
  'New Jersey': 56},
 'Richard': {'New York': 76,
  'Texas': None,
  'Florida': 43,
  'Arizona': None,
  'New Mexico': None,
  'New Jersey': 76},
 'Stephanie': {'New York': None,
  'Texas': 23,
  'Florida': None,
  'Arizona': None,
  'New Mexico': None,
  'New Jersey': None},
 'Rebecca': {'New York': None,
  'Texas': None,
  'Florida': 28,
  'Arizona': None,
  'New Mexico': 56,
  'New Jersey': None},
 'Charles': {'New York': None,
  'Texas': None,
  'Florida': None,
  'Arizona': 23,
  'New Mexico': 76,
  'New Jersey': None},
 'Anne': {'New York': None,
  'Texas': None,
  'Florida': None,
  'Arizona': 31,
  'New Mexico': None,
  'New Jersey': None},
 'William': {'New York': None,
  'Texas': None,
  'Florida': None,
  'Arizona': 44,
  'New Mexico': 63,
  'New Jersey': None},
 'Stephen': {'New York': None,
  'Texas': None,
  'Florida': None,
  'Arizona': None,
  'New Mexico': 21,
  'New Jersey': 45}}
```

Comment: Yep, populating set of values for all states needed to be done. Thank you so much